# как инициализировать переменную в скрипте через UI InputField Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

В UI Unity создал поле InputField, ввожу туда данные, нажимаю Button запуская **метод** который должен введенные данные присвоить переменной в скрипте. Вопрос что должно быть в этом методе?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в inputField  хранится значение text в котором и лежит ваше введенное значение. Вам нужно его спарсить и внести в нужную переменную

Вот так можно спарсить значение

```
  int result = 0;
  int.TryParse("12",out result);
```

Вам нужна ссылка на InputField.

Легче всего будет просто инициализировать её с юнити.

```
 [SerializeField] private InputFiedl input;
```

Затем в методе вашей кнопки делаете следующее.

```
nomen = input.text;
```

Comment: Вопрос как раз в том, как правильно ее спарсить (изъять) из значения text.

Comment: @Game-OFF, я обновил ответ

Comment: В Text лежит введенное значение "N43". Нужно спарсить в string(хотя на сколько я понимаю оно уже string.

Comment: это значение уже строка.  Вам стоит почитать о регулярных выражениях. Ну или можете просто рассмотреть строку как массив символов. Если у вас там всегда будет N43 в том смысле что что первым символом будет N

Comment: public class InputText : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Существует переменная в скрипте InputText
    public string nomen = " ";
    //запускаю Unity, нажимаю плей, ввожу в InputField данные(например F23)
    //как F23 присвоить переменной nomen что бы работать с ней далее.
    //до этого изучал C++, с Unity работаю неделю...Если можно ответ для дураков.
}